# polars and applying a UDF by column

Tags: python, python-polars

Importing text into a polars series arranges data in columns, which is what make polars (arrow) so efficient. The method `apply` will calculate a user-defined function (UDF) across rows but not columns. So I am in search of the fastest method to apply my UDF across each column.

This does what I need but it results in a 1 x n df with encapsulated series that are a pain to unpack. Does anyone have a better idea to unpack this or how to apply by columns?

Thanks!

Currently, I `select` and use `map` as follows on a 2000 x n df:

```py
df_baseline_series = df.select([
        pl.col('*').map(lambda y: get_baseline(y.to_numpy()))
    ])
```

The function `get_baseline` uses a `scikit-ued`function to return a `np.ndarray`:

```py
baseline_dt(data, wavelet='qshift3', level=6, max_iter=1)
```

This gives me an 1 x n df, with each element being a doubly-nested series (i.e., a series of a series).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself.

The map function needs a series returned and not a 1d numpy array.

So it works fine if `get_baseline` returns this:

```py
pl.Series(baseline_dt(data, wavelet='qshift3', level=6, max_iter=1))
```